# Could not open port error immediately after plugging in Arduino on Arch Linux

Tags: arduino, archlinux, platformio

I am using PlatformIO for programming and Arduino Mega and an Arduino Uno. I have them hooked up through serial, so I have to disconnect them from each other every time I want to program them. I also unplug them from the computer so that I don't accidentally fry them while moving wires around.

Every time I plug one or the other back in and try to program it immediately, I get this error message:

```
*** [upload] could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

If I wait for about a minute and try again, then the code will be uploaded no problem. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ModemManager might be the cause of your troubles. Try disabling it with, e.g. `pkill -STOP ModemManager` (continue the process with `-CONT`).

ModemManager is a (fantastic) piece of software that makes your 3G dongles work automagically. Because the Arduino appears as a serial modem, ModemManager tries to take control over it.

You can stop ModemManager from doing that by attaching a certain variable to your device. See [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/api/1.8.0/ref-overview-modem-filter.html) for details. Essentially, create a udev rule, e.g. `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-ttyacms.rules` with the following content:

`ATTRS{idVendor}=="0ca6" ATTRS{idProduct}=="a050", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1`

Of course, you need to use your IDs. Use `lsusb` to find those values.

After you have created this file, reload udev with something like `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

Comment: This worked! It looks like ModemManager is for mobile broadband. I don't need this - can I just remove ModemManager?